# Specifying the output namespace of a TextTemplatingFilePreprocessor t4 file

Tags: c#, msbuild, t4

Trying to build some output at runtime based on T4 templates.  I have the template, it seems to be working fine, until I try to build it via msbuild.  At this point, the templates are getting the top-level namespace instead of the directory-specific namespace that Visual Studio 2019 is giving them.  This means that if I build the code in VS, I get one thing, and if I build the code in our CI tools, I get a totally different thing.  Obviously, this isn't going to work.

I have

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets" />
```

in my csproj file, but when I run msbuild, I get output like this:

```
ExecuteTransformations:
  Performing full T4 transformation
  Performing full T4 preprocessing
  Preprocessing template Templates\MyMaster.tt...
  Preprocessing template Templates\Pdf\MyType.tt...
```

and all of the generated cs files are in the `Root` namespace.  My expectation is that they get the same as Visual Studio, which would be `Root.Templates` and `Root.Templates.Pdf`.

The csproj for the files look like this:

```
<Content Include="Templates\MyMaster.tt">
  <Generator>TextTemplatingFilePreprocessor</Generator>
  <LastGenOutput>MyMaster.cs</LastGenOutput>
</Content>
```

Any way to get the pre-build to have the correct namespaces would be great. I'd rather not try to fall back to a pre-build script that re-mangles the generated cs files

Comment: Why not just add the desired `namespace Root.Templates { ... }` to your tt file?

Comment: I'm not building a cs file, this is a runtime template.  The template is to produce html (which is then later used to produce a pdf).  The build-time generated cs code will be invoked at runtime to generate the actual output.  However, I have no idea how to get that cs file to have the correct namespace both in VS and in MSBuild.

Answer (score 1):

What should be the solution, is to use the `<CustomToolNamespace>` tag as [specified in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-items?view=vs-2022), but as far as I can tell, the TextTemplatingFilePreprocessor doesn't honour that.

I worked around it by changing it to `<ClassNamespace>`, i.e.

```xml
<Content Include="Templates\MyMaster.tt">
  <ClassNamespace>Your.Namespace.Here</ClassNamespace>
  <Generator>TextTemplatingFilePreprocessor</Generator>
  <LastGenOutput>MyMaster.cs</LastGenOutput>
</Content>
```

You'll have to add this line for every defined template file.

Comment: The `<CustomToolNamespace>` property is used when the T4 preprocessing happens within Visual Studio at design-time, while it's MSBuild/build-time T4 that uses `<ClassNamespace>`. You can also specify `<ClassName>` too, if you don't like the auto-generated class name.